# bash error: curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Tags: bash

**Here is the actual script:**

```
token="SEC: xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"    
addurl="https://10.10.10.1/api/reference_data/sets/IP-List"

for a in $(cat TEST-IP_List.csv); do    
    addcontent="$(curl -X POST -k -H "$token" "$addurl$a")"    
    echo "$addcontent"    
done
```

**The error im getting:**

```
[root@server406 Test]# ./test.sh    
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
```

Comment: What's hiding out in here: `TEST-IP_List.csv`

Comment: one column with no header. list of IP addresses

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line"; #your stuff here; done < TEST-IP_List.csv`

Comment: Something -- either the file or the script -- contains illegal characters, probably non-printing ones. Put `set -x` before the loop so the shell will print the equivalent of what's being executed, which should give you a better idea where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Alternatively, try `cat -v yourscript` in a console. If it shows weird characters like `^M`, you have hidden characters polluting your script

Comment: Still getting the same error. However  I just tried it on Ubuntu "" Windows Subsystem for Linux" and it ran with no issue. When i run on an actual Linux server (CentOS 7.6)" Windows Subsystem for Linux" it gives the curl error. Anyone knows why ?